# Encoding the string as UTF8 by using the enc2utf8

Tags: r, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm using R to attempt to do a sentiment analysis from public Reddit interactions about diabetes.

This is my sessioninfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

I successfully extracted the dataset using the RedditExtractor library. However, when I run the "sentiment" command from the SentimentAnalysis package, I get the following error message:

Error in FUN(content(x), ...): invalid multibyte string 1

I know the problem is not my code and the error has something to do with "characters not recognized by the character encoding format."

**How can I use the function *enc2utf8* to encode the string as UTF8?**

Please check the code below:

library("RedditExtractoR")
Diabetes_Dataset <- get_reddit(subreddit = "diabetes",page_threshold = 5, sort_by= "comments")
library("SentimentAnalysis")
sentiment <- analyzeSentiment(Diabetes_Dataset$comment)

I tried the following but got the same error:

enc2utf8(sentiment <- analyzeSentiment(Diabetes_Dataset$comment))

**Error in FUN(content(x), ...) : invalid multibyte string 1**

I appreciate any help anyone can provide. Thank you

Comment: I would suggest slightly restructuring the question by placing the most important information first. The most important information here is that you are using R (most people do NLP in Python). So if you want the question to be found by R experts, you should mention R language and your environment (OS, other details) explicitly. After that the error message: it is not likely that your error is specific to sentiment analysis, it is more likely related to simple text processing issues. Then the rest of the details.

Comment: I'm not an R expert, but "invalid multibyte string" is suggestive of an inverse problem: it is more likely to happen when you are reading a string that is already utf8 with a function that does not expect utf-8. Check if your library has explicit encoding parameters.